# Find and remove the packages that provides desktops environments

Tags: fedora, package-management, desktop-environment, dnf

Recently upgraded to Fedora 22; I now have the following desktop environments to choose from at login:

Gnome
Gnome Classic
Gnome Wayland
Plasma (KDE)
Kodi
Xmonad

How do I remove items from this list? I performed

```
sudo dnf groupremove xmonad
```

and its still in the list, though defunct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
#dnf group remove "KDE Plasma Workspaces"
```

Also you can provide list of your groups:

```
#dnf grouplist hidden |grep -i kde
#dnf grouplist hidden |grep -i gnome
```

Then select one of them as argument of `group remove`